# Generic Queue (Array and Linked List) Implementation

Tags: java, reinventing-the-wheel, queue

I am working on brushing up my data-structures knowledge, and was hoping to have my code/thoughts reviewed.

### Interface:

```
package dataStructures;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

    public interface QueueInterface<E> {
    /**
     * Puts an element into the queue and returns this interface to allow method chaining.
     * 
     * @param element
     *            - A generic element to add to the queue
     * @return QueueInterface to allow method chaining.
     */
    QueueInterface<E> add(E element);

    /**
     * Returns the first element in the queue. Throws an exception if there are no elements in the queue.
     * 
     * @return The first element in the queue
     * @throws NoSuchElementException
     *             When there are no elements in the queue
     */
    E element() throws NoSuchElementException;

    /**
     * Returns the first element, and removes it from the queue. Throws an exception if there are no elements in the queue.
     * 
     * @return The first element in the queue
     * @throws NoSuchElementException
     *             When there are no elements in the queue
     */
    E remove() throws NoSuchElementException;

    /**
     * Attempt to add an element to the queue. Returns true if it was successful.
     * 
     * @param element
     *            - A generic element to add to the queue
     * @return true if the element was added to the queue.
     */
    boolean offer(E element);

    /**
     * @return the first element in the queue. Returns null if the queue is empty.
     */
    E peek();

    /**
     * @return the first element and remove it from the queue. Returns null if the queue is empty.
     */
    E poll();
}
```

### Generic Array:

```
package dataStructures;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class GenericArrayQueue<T> implements QueueInterface<T> {
    private T[] data;
    private int front, size, back;

    public final static int DEFAULT_INITIAL_ARRAY_SIZE = 16;
    /**
     * MAX_ARRAY_SIZE is set to Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8 to prevent OutOfMemoryErrors.
     */
    public static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;

    public GenericArrayQueue() {
        this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_ARRAY_SIZE);
    }

    public GenericArrayQueue(int capacity) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (capacity < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Queue capacity must be 1 or greater");
        }

        if (capacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack capacity is greater then maximum array size");
        }

        // Data variable is private so it will never be returned to the client
        // and the only method that can push elements onto the array would have to be the same type so it is OK
        // to suppress the warning message.
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] tempData = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
        data = tempData;
    }

    @Override
    public QueueInterface<T> add(T e) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (size == data.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ran out of memory to queue");
        }

        data[back] = e;
        back = (back + 1) % data.length;
        size++;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public T element() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue does not contain any items.");
        }

        return data[front];
    }

    @Override
    public T remove() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue does not contain any items.");
        }

        size--;
        T output = data[front];
        data[front] = null;
        front = (front + 1) % data.length;
        return output;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(T e) {
        if (size == data.length) {
            return false;
        }

        size++;
        data[back] = e;
        back = (back + 1) % data.length;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T peek() {
        return size == 0 ? null : data[front];
    }

    @Override
    public T poll() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        T output= data[front];
        data[front] = null;
        front = (front + 1) % data.length;
        return output;
    }
}
```

### Generic Linked List:

```
package dataStructures;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class GenericLinkedListQueue<E> implements QueueInterface<E> {
    private Node<E> first, last;

    private static class Node<E> {
        private E data;

        private Node<E> back;

        public Node(E element) {
            data = element;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public QueueInterface<E> add(E element) {
        Node<E> newElement = new Node<E>(element);
        if (first == null) {
            first = newElement;
        } else {
            if (first.back == null) {
                first.back = newElement;
            } else {
                last.back = newElement;
            }

            last = newElement;
        }

        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public E element() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (first == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue does not contain any items.");
        }

        return first.data;
    }

    @Override
    public E remove() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (first == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue does not contain any items.");
        }

        E output = first.data;
        first = first.back;
        return output;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e) {
        // Only way for the offer to return false is if we run out of VM memory.
        add(e);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E peek() {
        return first == null ? null : first.data;
    }

    @Override
    public E poll() {
        if (first == null) {
            return null;
        }

        E output = first.data;
        first = first.back;

        return output;
    }

}
```

### JUnit

```
package dataStructures;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotEquals;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class QueueTest {

    QueueInterface<String> queueTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        queueTest = new GenericLinkedListQueue<>();
        // queueTest = new GenericArrayQueue<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        queueTest.add("5");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());
        queueTest.add("4");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());
        queueTest.add("3");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());
        queueTest.add("2");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());
        queueTest.add("1");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());

        assertEquals("5", queueTest.remove());
        assertEquals("4", queueTest.remove());
        assertEquals("3", queueTest.remove());
        assertEquals("2", queueTest.remove());
        assertEquals("1", queueTest.remove());
    }

    @Test
    public void testElement() {
        queueTest.add("5");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());
        queueTest.add("4");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());
        queueTest.add("3");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());
        queueTest.add("2");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());
        queueTest.add("1");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.element());
    }

    @Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
    public void testElementError() {
        queueTest.element();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRemove() {
        queueTest.add("5");
        queueTest.add("4");
        queueTest.add("3");
        queueTest.add("2");
        queueTest.add("1");    

        assertEquals("5", queueTest.remove());
        assertEquals("4", queueTest.remove());
        assertEquals("3", queueTest.remove());
        assertEquals("2", queueTest.remove());
        assertEquals("1", queueTest.remove());
    }

    @Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
    public void testRemoveError() {
        queueTest.remove();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPeek() {
        assertEquals(null, queueTest.peek());
        queueTest.add("5");
        assertNotEquals(null, queueTest.peek());
        queueTest.remove();
        assertEquals(null, queueTest.peek());
    }

    @Test
    public void testPoll() {
        assertEquals(null, queueTest.poll());
        queueTest.add("5");
        assertEquals("5", queueTest.poll());
        assertEquals(null, queueTest.poll());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to your array implementation of Stack ([Stack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139737)), there are some discrepancies:
1: Your Stack resizes its inner array when it is full, your Queue throws an exception. That's weird. I would expect a Queue to resize as well.

2: Your Stack has a `peek()` method that throw an exception if the Stack is empty. That's good. Your Queue also has a `peek()` method, but it returns `null` instead of throwing.
However, the queue does have a method that throws, but it has a different name: `element()`. This is very confusing. If two similar classes both have the same method, you might want to be consistent.

I'd say `peek()` should throw. If someone wants to peek, they should check if the collection is empty. Why have a method that returns `null`?
It is possible that the queue contains the value `null`. What if I call `peek()` and it returns `null`? What does that mean? Was the queue empty or did it contain the value `null`? I wouldn't know the difference.

I don't care much for a linked list implementation. Stack and Queue should be implemented with arrays anyway.

Comment: For this implementation I was attempting to use the interface from oracle: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). This is why the array does not resize since that is not what the interface was expecting to do.

Comment: @user3610520 I see. That makes sense. But I think the Java collections library is a bit messed up. Queue is an interface when it should be a class, and LinkedList implements Queue. That's weird.